# asp.net read ANSI non-English text file gives gibberish (how to convert to Unicode / UTF-8)

Tags: asp.net, encoding, utf-8, ansi, hebrew

I have a simple webform application with a label and a button. Clicking the button makes the C# code behind read a text file and display it in the label.
Works fine when all text in the text file is English, but all Hebrew characters are being displayed as question marks.

**C# code behind :**

```
string inputString;
lbl_Message_1.Text = "";
using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(@"E:\gadi_1.txt"))
{
    inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (inputString != null)
    {
        lbl_Message_1.Text += inputString + "<br />";
        inputString = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**The text file :**

```
line1
שורה2
line3
```

**In my Site.Master :**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

**The result :**
[image]

I've read numerous articles here and elsewhere and tried all but none helped.
Tried adding in my web.config :

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Also :

```
<globalization requestEncoding="windows-1255" responseEncoding="windows-1255" />
```

The second one (windows-1255) just changed the shape of the question marks :
[image]

Please see if you can help here.

**Edit:**
I opened the text file in Notepad, did "Save As..." and saw at the bottom 4 option for encoding :
[image]
The default is ANSI and that's where the trouble is. If I pick any of the other 3 and save - **IT WORKS FINE!**

**So my question now is :** Since in real life I cannot change the encoding of the text file, how do I determine the encoding which the text file uses, and how do I deal with it at the C# level in my Webform application?

Comment: are you using asp.net webforms or MVC?

Comment: Webform.   Sorry...should have mentioned it.